# SQLite + Python Data not saved in DB file

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my first project with `SQLite`.
The code runs perfect I checked and the lines look perfect.
I supposed that due to lack of knowledge of `SQLite` I'm making a mistake.

Problem: The code runs perfect no problem. But when I finish it doesn't `print` the **values** or even **save** the **values** in the `.db` file.

Full Code:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect('covid.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    covidTrack(
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    ph_number INTEGER,
    datestamp TEXT,
    keyword TEXT)''')


i_name = input('Please insert FULL NAME : \n ...')
i_email = input('Please insert EMAIL : \n ...')
i_number = input('Please insert PHONE NUMBER : \n ...')
print('Your data has been saved for acelerated contact, thank you.')

time.sleep(3)


def data_entry():
    c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(?,?,?)',
    (i_name, i_email, i_number))

conn.commit()

def dynamic_data_entry():
    keyword = nameofvenue
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s'))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(date, keyword)')

conn.commit()


def read_from_db():
    c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack
    WHERE datestamp
    BETWEEN "2021-02-06 14:50:00" AND "2021-02-06 15:00:00"''')
conn.commit()

for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)


create_table()
data_entry()
dynamic_data_entry()
read_from_db()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

I suppose if something wrong with the way I use `conn.commit()`.

Comment: You need to do `conn.commit()` after you execute the SQL statement (i.e. inside the function. At the moment you don't commit. The lines conn.commit() after functions definition do nothing. Indent them to be part of the function. Also, you better pass arguments, not use globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect('covid.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    covidTrack(
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    ph_number INTEGER,
    datestamp TEXT,
    keyword TEXT)''')


i_name = input('Please insert FULL NAME : \n ...')
i_email = input('Please insert EMAIL : \n ...')
i_number = input('Please insert PHONE NUMBER : \n ...')

print('Your data has been saved for acelerated contact, thank you.')

time.sleep(3)


def data_entry():
    date, keyword = dynamic_data_entry()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (i_name, i_email, i_number, date, keyword))
    conn.commit()


def dynamic_data_entry():
    keyword = 'nameofvenue'
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s'))
    return date, keyword


def read_from_db():
    c.execute('''SELECT * FROM covidTrack''')
    conn.commit()


create_table()
data_entry()
read_from_db()

for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Still the same, I run the code, asks me for the inputs and then closes. When I go to the `.db` file is empty.

Comment: Hmm.. I copy-pasted the code above and it worked for me. And there is no covidTrack table?

Comment: I have the file and the table but the data is never there. I tried manually writing the data i.e: `c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES("Alejandro Trin2020","06022021","CAFE")'` and the data was in the table no problem. Then I tried this that I found... `c.execute('''INSERT INTO
    covidTrack (name, email, ph_number, datestamp, keyword)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)''', (i_name, i_email, i_number, date, keyword))
    conn.commit()` but is the same, no data in the table. As well I tried without dynamic_data_entry to make it more simple and try to figure it out, but still the same problem.

Comment: Now I figured out that running your code on Command Prompt gives me this tacebrack: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ale\Desktop\Python projects\SQlite\ei.py", line 46, in <module>
    data_entry()
  File "C:\Users\Ale\Desktop\Python projects\SQlite\ei.py", line 29, in data_entry
    date, keyword = dynamic_data_entry()
  File "C:\Users\Ale\Desktop\Python projects\SQlite\ei.py", line 36, in dynamic_data_entry
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s'))
ValueError: Invalid format string`

Comment: Traceback fixed I was using the wrong format for the time. Now it works perfect and saves the data. really thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

change the code below (make the commit call part of the function that insert the data). Do it in  `dynamic_data_entry` as well

```
def dynamic_data_entry():
    keyword = nameofvenue
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s'))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(date, keyword)')

conn.commit()
```

to

```
def dynamic_data_entry():
    keyword = nameofvenue
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s'))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES(date, keyword)')
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Now I've included the `conn.commit()` to the dynamic_data_entry and data_entry. But still not saving the data in the .db

Comment: move `i_name = input('Please insert FULL NAME : \n ...')
i_email = input('Please insert EMAIL : \n ...')
i_number = input('Please insert PHONE NUMBER : \n ...')
print('Your data has been saved for acelerated contact, thank you.')` into ` data_entry`

Comment: After breaking down the code I realise that the problem is the use of `variables` for `data_entry`. Replacing the variables for: `c.execute('INSERT INTO covidTrack VALUES("Alejandro Trin2020","06022021","CAFE")')` it works perfectly, I mean, saves the data in `.db`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually commiting your executes. Move **conn.commit** after actual executes.

Comment: After moving `conn.commit()` inside the executes still not saving the data into the `.db`. Now I'm completely lost.